# Print a string separated by dots in reverse order

Tags: linux, string, bash, perl, shell

I need to print a string in reverse order in bash shell.

```
[deeps@host1:~]echo maps.google.com|rev
moc.elgoog.spam
[deeps@host1:~]
```

But I need it as "com.google.maps". I need it in general for any string separated by period (`.`).

It should print in reverse order. How do I do that?

I need the solution in Perl as well.

Answer (score 10):

Split by `.` then reverse the results, then join them up again.

> Perl Command Switches:
>
> `-l` means "remove/add the newline character from input/output."
>
> `-p` means "execute the program for each line of input, and print `$_` after each execution."
>
> `-e` means "the following argument is the code of the program to run."

[perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for more details.

```
echo maps.google.com | perl -lpe '$_ = join ".", reverse split /\./;'
```

**output**

```
com.google.maps
```

---

It also works if you have a data file with lots of rows.

**input**

```
maps.google.com
translate.google.com
mail.google.com
```

**run**

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join ".", reverse split /\./;' input
```

**output**

```
com.google.maps
com.google.translate
com.google.mail
```

Comment: Use `-l` to avoid the `chomp` and the `print "\n"`

Comment: Thanks  @hobbs.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the updates.

Answer (score 3):

Using a **bunch of utils**:

```
$ tr '.' $'\n' <<< 'maps.google.com' | tac | paste -s -d '.'
com.google.maps
```

This replaces all periods with newlines (`tr`), then reverses the order of the lines (`tac`), then pastes the lines serially (`paste -s`), with the period as the delimiter (`-d '.'`).

Considerably uglier (or just wordier?) in **pure Bash**:

```
# Read string into array 'arr', split at periods by setting IFS
IFS=. read -a arr <<< 'maps.google.com'

# Loop over array from the end
for (( i = $(( ${#arr[@]}-1 )); i >= 0; --i )); do

    # Append element plus a period to result string
    res+=${arr[i]}.
done

# Print result string minus the last period
echo "${res%.}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo maps.google.com | awk -F. '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==1?"\n":".")}'
com.google.maps
```

#### How it works

- `-F.`

  This tells awk to use a period as the field separator
- `for (i=NF;i>0;i--) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==1?"\n":".")`

  This loops over all fields, starting with the last and ending with the first and printing them, followed by a period (except for the first field which is followed by a newline).

  The one tricky part above is `(i==1?"\n":".")`.  This is called a *ternary statement*.  The part before the `?` is a logical condition.  If the condition is true then the value after the question mark, but before the `:`, is used.  If it is false, then the value after the `:` is used.  In this case, that means that, when we are on the first field `i==1`, then the statement returns a newline, `\n`.  If we are on any other field, it returns a period, `.`.  We use this to put a period after all the fields except for the first (which, in the output, is printed last).  After it, we put a newline.

  For more on *ternary statements*, see the [GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp).

Comment: can you please let me know how does '(i==1?"\n":".")' work?

Comment: @deeps Good point.  I have added an explanation and link to documentation for _ternary statements_.

Comment: thanks @john1024 for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Perl:

```
$str = "maps.google.com";
@arr =split('\.',$str);
print join(".",reverse @arr);
```

output:

> com.google.maps

Split the string on "." and reverse the array. Join the reversed array using ".".